# Bug in chrome extension (manifest v3) messaging passing blocks map objects

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, message-passing

I'm developing a Chrome extension which scrappes some data via content scripts and passes one composite object to the background worker.

In the passed object, I have many properties. Some are strings, some are integers, some arrays and 3 of them are `Map` objects.

The thing is: these `Map` objects are stripped in the proccess. I `console.log` the same object immediatelly before sending and after receiving, and the 3 properties which are `Map` objects become empty objects:

In content script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (msg.attemptedStartScrapping) {
        try {
            fetchInfo()
                .then(info => {
                    console.log({content: info})
                    sendResponse(info)
                })
            return true
        } catch (e) {
            if(!(e instanceof NotHomepageException)) console.error(e)
        }
    }
})
```

In bg worker:

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
    const details = { tabId: tab.id }
    sendMessage(details)
})

function sendMessage(details) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
        details.tabId,
        {
            attemptedStartScrapping: true,
            tabId: details.tabId ?? null,
        },
        info => {
            console.log({ worker: info })
        }
    )
}
```

Console outputs:

[image] [image]

Any thoughts? Did we find a bug in message passing?

Comment: you can't send map\set objets and anyway object that can't be serialized.
In your case you can transform map in 2 distinc arrays of keys and values or better a new object.

Comment: Thanks! The associated question answers mine. I don't want to delete it, though, because with this title it's easier for other people facing the same problem to find it on search engines.